# Excel->Fill Data (Ctrl+D)->Increment by more than 1 in the formula

Tags: excel, increment

So if I have A1= 1  and A2= A1+1, then I highlight A2 down a couple of rows, and Fill Data with Ctrl+D, I will get something like this (Formulaic view):

> A1 Value
>
> =A2+1
>
> =A3+1
>
> ...And so on

So instead of having A1, A2, A3 (the reference cell increment by 1) I would like to increment it by 12, so it should look like this:

> A1 Value
>
> =A(1+12)+1.............which is A13+1
>
> =A(1+12+12)+1......... which is A25+1
>
> ...And so on

Detail Explanation: I have rows of monthly data, and I just want to grab  yearly rows from these monthly rows, so I want a step of 12 when I do Ctrl+D to pull the monthly rows into a yearly rows presentation/computation.

Thank you for your time.

Concrete Example:

> =IF(SUM(Enacted!**AM158**:AM169)>0,1,"")
>
> =IF(SUM(Enacted!**AM170**:AM181)>0,1,"")
>
> =IF(SUM(Enacted!**AM182**:AM193)>0,1,"")

There is an indirect solution offer, but it would obscure the formulas and make it really complicated for other people to understand or edit this excel.  So I am hoping for someway to directly update these formulas.

Answer (score 1):

If you start this formula in ROW 1 then you can use this formula:

`=INDIRECT("A" & ((ROW()-x)*12)+1)`

Otherwise you can insert the first row with this formula in place of the "x". If you start this formula at row 2, then the formula will be: `=INDIRECT("A" & ((ROW()-2)*12)+1)`

and so on.

Comment: I like your solution but have updated/clarify my question because I am hoping for a more direct way to update the formulas.  If none offered, I will accept your answer.  Thank you very much.